# Taking the difference of temporal fields in JPQL

Tags: jpa, jpa-2.0, jpql, temporal

I have an entity `Event` which has fields `startDate` and `endDate`. I'd like to select only those events that have at most `x` days left to the their `endDate`. I want to do this in JPQL and with only one query. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JPA does not provide any standard date/time functions.  You can use a native SQL query using SQL EXTRACT,

Or, if you are using EclipseLink you can use the FUNC JPQL operator to call a database specific function, or use EXTRACT if using EclipseLink 2.4,

See,

http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/UserGuide/JPA/Basic_JPA_Development/Querying/JPQL#Functions