# jpa difference in timestamp columns

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I have a JPA query to compute differnce between two timestamp columns .

select ( endTime - startTime ) from myTable

The value is getting returned  as secons in MySQL.
But in Oracle , its  coming in a differnt format +000000000 02:10:48

Is there anyway to get the time difference between two timestamp columns in JPA in the same format in MySQL and Oracle ?

Answer (score 1):

JPA does not define any functions on time fields: see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10578597/taking-the-difference-of-temporal-fields-in-jpql). What you could do is the following: select both fields endTime and startTime in your JPQL and make the substraction in Java.

Comment: Thanks.I need to select only those records whose time diffence is greater than a specified value .so I need this condition in the WHERE condition also. It works fine in MySQL but in ORACLE ,it returns incorrect value